# what is the meaning of 'Actresses are now casting the couch aside'?

Tags: meaning, idioms, headlinese

What is the meaning of 'Actresses are now casting the couch aside'?
Source: https://www.msn.com/en-in/news/other/actresses-are-now-casting-the-couch-aside/vp-BBwwpWg

*Cast aside* means

> 1. To physically move something that is blocking one's path. A noun or pronoun can be used between "cast" and "aside."
> 2. To ignore, overlook, or reject someone or something. A noun or pronoun can be used between "cast" and "aside."

Reference: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cast+aside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a play on the well-known expression [*casting couch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_couch) (Wikipedia):

> The casting couch, casting-couch syndrome, or casting-couch mentality is the demanding of sexual favors by an employer or person in a position of power and authority, from an apprentice employee, or subordinate to a superior in return for entry into an occupation, or for other career advancement within an organization. The term casting couch originated in the motion picture industry, with specific reference to couches in offices that could be used for sexual activity between casting directors or film producers and aspiring actors. It is not to be confused with the adult entertainment industry where such actions may be a prerequisite, although many pornographic films and pornographic websites play on the casting couch theme and allude to similarities one may find in casting couch scenarios in the film industry.

Literally, the title of the clip means to move a couch aside. However, it is meant figuratively. It roughly means that actresses are rejecting the culture or requirement of having to do sexual favors in order to advance their careers.